# Careers 2.0: article link gets broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, hyperlinks, article

I have added the following URL to my profile as an article:
http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/MM.2010.78

The page gets retrieved ok during the initial edit, but the link that gets placed on the rendered profile page is:
http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/www.computer.org/csdl/mags/mi/2010/05/mmi2010050066-abs.html

This just shows an error, so I took just the last part (www.computer.org/csdl/mags/mi/2010/05/mmi2010050066-abs.html), which is a valid link, and added it again. This still gets re-written, this time as 
http://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/mi/2010/05/www.computer.org/csdl/mags/mi/2010/05/mmi2010050066-abs.html

This version of the link gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When indexing the document, we respect the rel=canonical meta tag. In the case of the document above, it's broken. It reads

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.computer.org/csdl/mags/mi/2010/05/mmi2010050066-abs.html"/>
```

...which is interpreted as a relative URL, because is lacks a scheme (http). I'll see if we can work around it. If you happen to know the webmaster at computer.org, ask them to correct it.

Comment: FYI, I have contacted the webmaster (via the email listed on their website) with a link to this very question. Let's see if they respond. In case they do (and don't do so here) I will add their reply.

Comment: And a reply has been received. I quote: "Thank you Bart for the email.
We confirmed this and are fixing it. We will let you know once the fix is deployed."

Comment: Ah, excellent, thanks for contacting them. I had assumed it was just using redirect headers to decide what the final destination page was. So now I have learned something new about canonical URLs too :)

Comment: I can confirm that they've fixed it and the link is now working correctly. Thanks everyone!